# dll integration into Axapta 3.0

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I wants to integrate com object 'dll' into Axapta 3.0.
Note:['DLL' is the WCF client class which consumes Web Service.]

**What i did is:**
Make dll in .Net 3.5 ver.
Sign the assembly 'dll' with strong password.
Put the assembly 'dll' in Navision/Axapta client/Bin folder.
Registered the dll with regasm command with administrative privilage.

**Although:** 
I can see my assembly dll in the COM object wizard.
Assembly classes are imported successfully in AOT-Class.

**BUT:**
When i create a job to access the class and run it. it gives error:

COM object of class '{88E77BBE-D3BC-3D8B-8C57-606699D7CDB7}' could not be created. Ensure that the object has been properly registered on computer 'KASHIF-NYPC'.

Alternatively, i create a simple but dummy HelloWorld Class 'DLL' with Ping method. And injects the same steps as mentions above and it integarated well into Axapta 3.0. The Ping method be access successfully from Axapta 3.0 through a job.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Kashif

Comment: [Same question](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/200467) in [AX Community Development / Customization / SDK forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33?pi53287=0&category=Development%20%2F%20Customization%20%2F%20SDK)

Comment: Is it a batch job that executes on the server/AOS service?  If so you would also need to register the dll on the server computer....  Also, is it possible to run the batch job as another account as what you are testing on?

Comment: No. Its not any batch job. Or nothing else to deal with the Server. I am just integrating the dll at client machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i find solution to my question/problem.

I wanted to integrate c# class ( consume WCF webservice) into Axapta 3.0.

So the problem didn't exist; the way COM object integration into Axapta 3.0.

But, the way client consumes the WCF webservice.

I was consuming the webservice as Service Reference and hence it arose an error in Axapta. Instead of 'ServiceReference', i consume WCF webservice as a 'WebReference' and it works well.

[Sample image: To add WCF as webreference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHGsK.png)